# Module not detected when code run from wsgi.py but detected when run from main.py

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to push my flask app to Heroku using this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/). When I run it from main.py which is in the app folder, my program works. But since I have an app folder, for Heroku I need another file outside the app to run that program. However, when I use wsgi.py to run the program instead, I get an error stating that converting module is not detected.

wsgi.py code and output from running here:

```
from app.main import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mpari\Documents\GitHub\Morse-Code-Translator\wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.main import *
  File "C:\Users\mpari\Documents\GitHub\Morse-Code-Translator\app\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from converting import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'converting'
```

If I run it from main, then my code works fine. Main is also where my flask app is.

```
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[image: Project Structure #1]

[image: Project Structure #2]

Comment: Show us your project structure!

Comment: @KlausD. I added screenshots for the project structure. I was not sure if you needed that. That's my bad.

Comment: Put the `wsgi.py` into the same folder as `main.py`. The module you are starting is going to define the base folder for imports.

Comment: Give `python -m wsgi` a shot this will run it as a module. Also, I tend to avoid using the wild card `from app.main import *` as it makes debugging issues like this more painful.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried that and I edited the procfile configuration file and now main is not being detected. However,  it works locally flawlessly so I think its some Heroku config error.

[I uploaded to a pastebin the logs and the file config](https://pastebin.com/KWvH28B8)

Comment: @darcycp I tried that but I think it's now a Heroku issue. Also I converted from main import * to from main import app as that's the name of my flask app.

Comment: Going off the config you mentioned to @KlausD I think you might be having issues with your entrypoint for Heroku. If you put the wsgi.py in the same folder as main.py make sure that Heroku's .git folder is also initialised inside of there and not in the parent directory.

Comment: @darcycp I'm using GitHub instead of Heroku git. And on Heroku, I am directly pulling code from my repo.